# Get Wifi signal strength with OpenNetCf in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, opennetcf

As the title says, I want to get the wireless signal strength from adapter on Windows CE, VB.Net, Visual studio 2008.

I believe opennetcf.net library has to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write any code for you but maybe I can at least point you in the right direction. In the beta documentation for [`OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/networkinformation/) you'll see a class called [`WirelessNetworkInterface`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/networkinformation/html/7232d8d7-2642-fc55-a79f-0ac6758914ca.htm) which has a [`SignalStrength`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/networkinformation/html/532f84d9-e9c9-5e14-87c6-e4aabda91b82.htm) property which returns a [`SignalStrength`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/networkinformation/html/9c58d8a0-99a8-7b0f-3940-0d36b3f646d4.htm) object.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem.
I tried to program it on Motorola MC3190 hand scanner with some stupid Motorola Jedi Wireless Drivers which are identifying the interface as ethernet instead of wireless and this is the reason why tehere is no such option.
I also tried few versions of Motorola EMDK's, but those are also not working with MC3190.